# Amazon S3 lifecycle rules: Archive files have recent dates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I am trying to enable  lifecycle rule for a s3 bucket to move the older files to s3 glacier deep archive, I am planning to keep 6 month files in s3 bucket and rest move to glacier.

But the problem is when I check the older files (which is of 2017) modified date is showing as 2020. If I am going to enable the lifecycle rule starting to archive files older than 180 days. I am not able to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I am not able to see the created date for the file apart from the listed file name.

Comment: Were these files uploaded to S3 in 2017? Were they modified since then? Do you know why they might be showing a date in 2020?

Comment: Seems likes the file was uploaded in 2017, but later they had created a folder and moved the files to it.

Comment: If you have a folder with "old" files that are showing recent dates, you could configure a temporary lifecycle rule that causes them to archive, then reset the rule for the normal 180 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afraid it only keeps he last modified date

> Amazon S3 maintains only the last modified date for each object. For example, the Amazon S3 console shows the Last Modified date in the object Properties pane. When you initially create a new object, this date reflects the date the object is created. If you replace the object, the date changes accordingly. So when we use the term creation date, it is synonymous with the term last modified date.

Sourced from: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/intro-lifecycle-rules.html#intro-lifecycle-rules-actions